# Verify syntax of JSON file from command-line (CLI sanity check)

Tags: command-line, bash, json

What's the simplest command that I can run on Ubuntu Linux to verify the sanity of a JSON file?

I have a very long JSON file that I just edited with `vim`. I want to make sure my changes didn't introduce any syntax errors.

I know I could write a python script for this, but I'd prefer something built-in and simpler.

Is there just some bash one-liner that I can run against the file that will tell me if (and where) there's any syntax issues with the JSON file?

Comment: `jq . file >/dev/null 2>&1 || echo error`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jq` and send stdout to null

```
sudo apt-get install jq
jq . /path/to/yourfile.json 1> /dev/null
```

### Example Execution

Here's some example runs

##### No Errors

If there are no errors in the json file, then there will be no output and the exit code is 0

```
user@host:~$ jq . updates/v1/meta.json 1> /dev/null
user@host:~$ echo $?
0
user@host:~$
```

##### Errors

If there are errors in the json file, then the output will tell you exactly which line & character, and the exit code will be non-zero

```
user@host:~$ jq . updates/v1/meta.json 1> /dev/null
parse error: Expected another array element at line 15, column 8
user@host:~$ echo $?
4
user@host:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install jsonlint
```

and then do `jsonlint-php {file}`

[Manual page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/en/man1/jsonlint-php.1.html):

```
OPTIONS

   -q, --quiet
          Cause jsonlint to be quiet when no errors are found

   -h, --help
          Show this message
```

Comment: I installed jsonlint with `sudo apt-get install jsonlint` but I didn't get any new binaries named `jsonlint` (confirmed with `dpkg-query -L jsonlint`) The only new binary that was installed was `jsonlint-php`. This is on Debian 11.

Comment: ah we changed that indeed. the apt is still correct.